# Why it seems impossible to use BeanUtils.copyProperties from a JPA entity to a JAX-B Bean?

Tags: spring, jaxb, entity, dto, apache-commons-beanutils

We are using JPA Entities to get the database rows and then when we transfer that to the external, we want to use disconnected object (DTO) which are simple beans annotated with JAX-B.

We use a mapper and its code looks like this:

```
public BillDTO map(BillEntity source, BillDTO target) {
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target);
    return target;
}
```

But when the code is running we get an error like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Note this is the Spring implementation of the BeanUtils:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils
```

And the naming of the properties are identical (with their getter/setter).

- Anybody knows why the error happens?
- And how to use a fast way instead just copying properties one by one?

Comment: Post full stack trace and add code of `BillDTO` or `BillEntity`

Comment: Hi, you point to the right way, in fact I found why it was not doing the job: one property in the DTO was an Enum as in the Entity it was a String. Even I added a new setter in the DTO that takes a String it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example working well. Here `String` property is copied to `enum` property:

**Entity:**

```
public class A {
   private String valueFrom;

   public String getValue() {
      return valueFrom;
   }

   public void setValue(String value) {
      this.valueFrom = value;
   }
}
```

**DTO**  (`En` is enumeration):

```
public class B {
   private En valueTo;

   public void setValue(String def) {
      this.valueTo = En.valueOf(def);
   }
   
   public void setEnumValue(En enumVal) {
      this.valueTo = enumVal;
   }
}
```

As for your GitHub example, problem in `class B` in getter should be:

```
public String getValue()
```

Example:

```
public String getValue() {
   return value.toString();
}
```

Comment: Which BeanUtils are you using? Spring one or Apache one?

Comment: I have a test similar here: https://gist.github.com/ruffp/5976432 result: variable c is properly set ("C") but b.getValue() stays null. But I do not have any Exception.

Comment: Ok thanks, I found in that case if you have null value in the source it generate the Exception. Finally I put the Enum in the JPA Entity, that way even the null values are copied.